# Simple Flip buffer (Vertically) issue in C\C++

Tags: c++, c, pixel, memcpy, flip

I am trying to flip a buffer, but the buffer doesn't get fully processed. 
Is a buffer of pixels and I need basically to flip it vertically.
Can anyone spot what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
void flipVertically(unsigned int* buffer, const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height)
{
    const unsigned int rowWidth = width; // Length of a row
    const unsigned int rows = height / 2; // Iterate only half the buffer to get a full flip
    unsigned int* tempRow = (unsigned int*)malloc(rowWidth);

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++)
    {
        memcpy(tempRow, buffer + (rowIndex * rowWidth), rowWidth);
        memcpy(buffer + (rowIndex * rowWidth), buffer + (height - rowIndex - 1) * rowWidth, rowWidth);
        memcpy(buffer + (height - rowIndex - 1) * rowWidth, tempRow, rowWidth);
    }

    free(tempRow);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `flip`? Do you mean reverse? Do you mean transpose? Is this C or C++? If it is C++, why are you using pointers?

Comment: What is `bufferPixels` ?

Comment: Exactly what goes wrong?

Comment: Note: You pass `rowWidth` to `memcpy` whereas you probably want `rowWidth * sizeof(*buffer)`.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I think it's a 2D array stored as sequentially in memory that needs to be flipped vertically (row[0] <-> row[w-1], row[1] <-> row[w-2], etc.).

Comment: @Dukeling Agreed, the question has been clarified. OP, I suggest you clarify your function name to `flip_vertically`.

Comment: If this is a project that will be used and maintained going forward, I would think about developing an interface that allowed me to use `std::reverse`, as it would improve readability.

Comment: rowWidth is the length of the row in bytes, or the length of the row in ints? The `malloc` suggests bytes, but the pointer arithmetic suggests ints.

Comment: For performance, have an array of "pointer to start of horizontal line" and construct it upside-down, and leave the buffer as is.

Comment: Brendan, could you supply an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will this work?

```
void flip(unsigned* buffer, unsigned width, unsigned height)
{
    unsigned rows = height / 2; // Iterate only half the buffer to get a full flip
    unsigned* tempRow = (unsigned*)malloc(width * sizeof(unsigned));

    for (unsigned rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++)
    {
        memcpy(tempRow, buffer + rowIndex * width, width * sizeof(unsigned));
        memcpy(buffer + rowIndex * width, buffer + (height - rowIndex - 1) * width, width * sizeof(unsigned));
        memcpy(buffer + (height - rowIndex - 1) * width, tempRow, width * sizeof(unsigned));
    }

    free(tempRow);
}
```